# Celery: How to retrieve metadata from custom states?

Tags: celery

The example for custom states show that metadata can be stored:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states

Which API can I use to retrieve the metadata associated with a result?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The example given is as follows:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def upload_files(self, filenames):
    for i, file in enumerate(filenames):
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
            meta={'current': i, 'total': len(filenames)})
```

When you setup the task, say

```
task = upload_files.delay(['happy.txt', 'sad.txt', ...])
```

You can access the meta info via task.result

Hope that helps

Answer (score 35):

The docs don't make it clear how to get the metadata from the result. Use AsyncResult.info.

```
>>> job = AsyncResult(job_id)
>>> print(job.info)
{'current': 2, 'total': 100}
```

Comment: Came here a lot later for some important info - `AsyncResult` does a _pretty_ good job of figuring out the Celery configuration it needs, but sometimes it can't find it. In these cases, run it with `AsyncResult(task_id, app=app)` or `AsyncResult(task_id, backend=x)`.

Comment: Forgot to include one other alternative - `app. AsyncResult(task_id)` will work as well.